# C# очищение поверхности Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

В главной форме проинициализирована переменная отвечающая за графику g = this.CreateGraphics(). Есть метод, который рисует окружность. Есть второй метод на событие click, который проводит горизонтальную и вертикальную линию в окружности. Вопрос, как затирать элементы независимо друг от друга? Например, я нажал на кнопку, нарисовалась горизонтальная линия, нажал еще раз на кнопку, горизонтальная линия пропала и нарисовалась вертикальная (при этом с окружностью ничего не должно происходить).

Comment: Напиши простой менеджер объектов который следит за состоянием объектов, подпишись на событие ОнПейнт и в нем уже перерисовывай как нужно.

Comment: Не могли бы привести простой пример кода?

Comment: Будет лучше, если Вы приведёте пример Вашего кода, на основе которого люди смогут Вам помочь, либо подсказать.

Comment: Независимо затереть не получится, можно только стереть всё, а затем нарисовать нужное.

Comment: В принципе, я так и сделал - все затер и заново нарисовал